# Laravel Blade Doesnt Display Return Ajax Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Data from Ajax to console screen, at the same time, when I look at Browser f12 Network, the data returns successfully as follows. But it does not show in div in some kind of index.blade.php file.

Response Json Data

```
{"options":"<table>\n  <thead>\n    <tr>\n        <th>Alt Grup<\/th>\n        <th>Miktar<\/th>\n    <\/tr>\n  <\/thead>\n  <tbody>\n                      <tr>\n              <td>AB<\/td>\n              <td>110<\/td>\n          <\/tr>\n                  <tr>\n              <td>AC<\/td>\n              <td>9<\/td>\n          <\/tr>\n           \n        \n  <\/tbody>\n<\/table>\n\n\n\n"}
```

Ajax Script in index.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.depo_sec').click(function(){
        var depo_id = $(this).children('input:hidden').eq(0).val();
            $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('stok-ajax') }}",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            method: 'POST',
            data: {depo_id:depo_id},
            success: function(dataHTML) {
                $('#ajax-area').html(dataHTML);
                console.log(dataHTML);
            }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to display ajax data into the **div id="ajax-area"**.

index.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="ajax-area"></div>
</div>
```

It does not give any errors but does not print anything on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your JSON return, you need

```js
$('#ajax-area').html(dataHTML.options);
```

instead of

```js
$('#ajax-area').html(dataHTML);
```

N.B: You should be very careful about that because injecting some HTML is a XSS vulnerability.